# Finding a datamodel online tools... from a picture

Tags: data-modeling, modeling, spring-data-graph, spring-data-neo4j

I read the docs for Spring Data Neo4j, and I found this kind of pictures:
[image: the unkown source]

It's really funny and I want use it too! Do you know what is the website that generates it? I know that it works with some script language, but I didn't find it after spent some hours :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used http://yuml.me for it, it has a nice textual DSL for creating those diagrams and you can have them render the image and you can include it directly into your web-pages.

Answer (score 0):

You can try http://grapholite.com/ . Just select one of the "Sketch" themes to get hand-drawing imitation. Also it's supports all UML shapes.